# How do I link to a non-default glibc library?

Tags: linux, gcc, compilation, cross-compiling

I have successfully cross-compiled a program on an x86-64 machine. However, when I try to run on my target machine sh4a, I get the following error:
./ioq3ded.sh4a: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.11' not found (required by ./ioq3ded.sh4a)

The details of the two machines are as follows:
Compiling machine
architecture: x86-64
LIBC version: 2.11

Executing mechine
architecture: sh4a
LIBC version: 2.5

Programming Language is C

Therefore, as a solution, I tried to compile a 2.11 LIBC library on the sh4a machine. However, it failed because the GCC compiler on the sh4a machine was too old, I don't have the authority, nor is there a possibility for upgrading the GCC.
Furthermore, as an alternative solution, I tried to compile a 2.5 LIBC library on the x86-64 so I can link to them during cross-compilation time. However, the ./configure failed because there were missing required objects.
Moreover, I tried to -static compile the program. However, it failed:
As for ioquake3, I tried to statically build it:
/bin/ld: /r/home7/usr/lib/libc.a(dl-tsd.o): TLS local exec code cannot be linked into shared objects
It seems impossible to statically build it with the old version of gcc we have.
I looked up this problem:
https://bugs.gentoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=122665

Moreover, I downloaded the LIBC 2.5 for x86-64 from the net:
http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/12884473/dir/startcom_5/com/glibc-2.5-34.x86_64.rpm.html[^]

However, I cannot seem to find the right flags for compiling so that it links against MY specific (2.5 version library) rather than the system ones (2.11 version library).

Here comes my question:
* What should be the "make" flags be? considering that the folder where MY (2.5 version library) is:
./glibc-2_5/lib64/libc.so
And, my make is as follows:
make USE_LOCAL_HEADERS=0 ARCH=sh4a CFLAGS='-fopenmp -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_REENTRANT'  USE_VOIP=0 BUILD_CLIENT=0 BUILD_MISSIONPACK=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply copy the Glibc files from the toolchain into the SH4A machine.

If you do not wish to overwrite the existing libc files then try a `chroot`, or, if that can't work for you, put them somewhere else, and then add the following options to your link command:

```
-Wl,-rpath,/path/to/alternative/lib -Wl,-dynamic-linker,/path/to/alternative/lib/ld-linux.so
```

The paths should be as they are on the SH4A target machine, not the x86_64 build machine.

Comment: Thank you for kind reply! After adding the options you kindly instructed, I got the following error on my sh4a machine: "ld-linux.so: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory". I tried to google for solutions, but everything was so irrelevant.

Comment: My make was like this: doesn't build an sh4a version make USE_LOCAL_HEADERS=0 CFLAGS='-fopenmp -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_REENTRANT -Wl,-rpath,/home/yasir/fromgunmar/lib -Wl,-dynamic-linker,/home/yasir/fromgunmar/lib/ld-linux.so' USE_VOIP=0 BUILD_CLIENT=0 BUILD_MISSIONPACK=0 BUILD_GAME_QVM=0

Comment: I also did this, and got a non-cross-compiled version: make USE_LOCAL_HEADERS=0 CFLAGS='-fopenmp -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_REENTRANT' FLAGS+= -Wl,-rpath,/home/yasir/fromgunmar/lib -Wl,-dynamic-linker,/home/yasir/fromgunmar/lib/ld-linux.so USE_VOIP=0 BUILD_CLIENT=0 BUILD_MISSIONPACK=0 BUILD_GAME_QVM=0

Comment: I don't know your build system, but the linker flags would normally go in `LDFLAGS`, not `CFLAGS`. The `/path/to/dynamic/linker` should be the path on the target, not the path on the host.

Comment: Where have you got your SH4A toolchain from?

Comment: I moved the linker flags to LDFLAGS, but I still got the same ELF error: doesn't build an sh4a version make USE_LOCAL_HEADERS=0 CFLAGS='-fopenmp -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_REENTRANT' LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath,/home/yasir/fromgunmar/lib -Wl,-dynamic-linker,/home/yasir/fromgunmar/lib/ld-linux.so.2" USE_VOIP=0 BUILD_CLIENT=0 BUILD_MISSIONPACK=0 BUILD_GAME_QVM=0

Comment: How do I find out what my toolchain is?

Comment: Well, you must have got it from somewhere? `gcc --version` is a good start.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20627/discussion-between-ams-and-user598208)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I live in a different time zone where it was late at night. anyway, gcc --version
gcc (crosstool-NG hg+default-369e2fbe9010) 4.4.6
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: This would be my last comment before I go to chat if needed: I couldn't find ld-linux.so on neither machine, but I was able to find x86-64%/lib/ld-linux.so.2. So, I copied all the lib files that I found here: x86-645 /lib* to sh4a%/path/to/alternative/lib/ However, I get a different error now: "-bash: ./ioq3ded.sh4a: Accessing a corrupted shared library" After searching, it seems that the cross-compiling built the file as a 64 and not 32-bit. I tried to enter the -m32 option, but the compiler said cannot recognize machine option "-m32". Thanx!

Comment: SH4A doesn't do 64-bit. That's only to do with the host machine you have your toolchain on. There should be a `libc.so.*` file somewhere in your toolchain install. The same for `ld-linux.so.*`. (You're right that the name I gave was only approximate.)

Comment: What's the difference between the host, target and build machines?

Comment: In a toolchain, the "target" is the machine the compiler outputs code for, the "host" is the machine the compiler runs on, and the "build" is the machine the compiler itself was built on. For example, it's not uncommon to create a compiler on x86 Linux, that will run on x86 Windows, and will be used for building ARM Linux programs.

Comment: In a more normal project, the "host" and "build" are pretty much the same thing. So your development PC, whatever that is, will be the host/build machine, and your SH4A board will be your "target" machine.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanations! Btw, it seems I was copying the incorrect library files. After, I copied the correct library files, your solution now work! Thank you for all the help! : D